# In Laravel, how can I obtain a list of all files in a public folder?

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I'd like to automatically generate a list of all images in my public folder, but I cannot seem to find any object that could help me do this.

The `Storage` class seems like a good candidate for the job, but it only allows me to search files within the storage folder, which is outside the public folder.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could create another disk for Storage class. This would be the best solution for you in my opinion.

In **config/filesystems.php** in the disks array add your desired folder. The **public** folder in this case.

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path().'/app',
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
    ],

    's3' => '....'
```

Then you can use **Storage** class to work within your public folder in the following way:

```
$exists = Storage::disk('public')->exists('file.jpg');
```

The $exists variable will tell you if **file.jpg** exists inside the **public** folder because the **Storage disk 'public'** points to public folder of project.

You can use all the **Storage** methods from documentation, with your custom disk. Just add the disk('public') part.

```
 Storage::disk('public')-> // any method you want from
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#basic-usage

*Later Edit:*

People complained that my answer is not giving the exact method to list the files, but my intention was never to drop a line of code that the op copy / paste into his project. I wanted to "teach" him, if I can use that word, how to use the laravel Storage, rather then just pasting some code.

Anyway, the actual methods for listing the files are:

```
$files = Storage::disk('public')->files($directory);

// Recursive...
$files = Storage::disk('public')->allFiles($directory);
```

And the configuration part and background are above, in my original answer.

Comment: Bonus for a more "laravelish" solution

Comment: this is a lengthy answer with 20 upvotes. Yet you don't answer the question of "list of all images in my public folder" and the laravel documentation apge doesn't really explain what Storage::allFiles() returns. Yes, an array, but what is inside the array? how do I get the filename and path from that?

Comment: My thoughts also. They didn't answer the question.

Comment: I don't get how the author of the question accepted this answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer because my question was more about how to use `Storage` on a public folder than the specifics of listing the files. So it solved my particular problem, but maybe the question does not reflect that enough.

Comment: `storage_path('app')` does the slashes for you

Comment: What is wrong with copy and paste? It's using a simple tool to save work, and that is what computers are for.

Answer (score 58):

`Storage::disk('local')->files('optional_dir_name');`

or just a certain type of file

```php
array_filter(Storage::disk('local')->files(), function ($item) {
   //only png's
   return strpos($item, '.png');
});
```

Note that laravel disk has `files()` and `allfiles()`.  `allfiles` is recursive.

Comment: thank you! i created a symbolic link so I can access photos via asset('storage/imgagName.jpg'), then foreached over Storage::disk('local')->files() to display them in a table on my view.

Comment: !warning: This is still puling every single files and iterating through each file

Comment: @Peter ya... that's array_filter(...)  What is your recommendation?

Answer (score 32):

Consider using [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). No need to overcomplicate barebones PHP with helper classes/methods in Laravel 5.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("/location/for/public/images/*.png") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: And seems like the most efficient for local file system

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`FilesystemReader::listContents`](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/usage/filesystem-api/)

```
Storage::disk('public')->listContents();
```

Sample response...

```
[
  [
    "type" => "file",
    "path" => ".gitignore",
    "timestamp" => 1600098847,
    "size" => 27,
    "dirname" => "",
    "basename" => ".gitignore",
    "extension" => "gitignore",
    "filename" => "",
  ],
  [
    "type" => "dir",
    "path" => "avatars",
    "timestamp" => 1600187489,
    "dirname" => "",
    "basename" => "avatars",
    "filename" => "avatars",
  ]
]
```

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: Note: you must be using the 3rd party package ("[Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/usage/filesystem-api/)") linked at the top of this answer.

Comment: Do you know how to get modified date of the file with the listContents

Answer (score 7):

Use the `File` Namespace for getting the public path. Then use this code to get all the files from the selected directory.

```
use File;
```

For example the public directory name is "media"

```
$mediaPath = public_path('media');
$filesInFolder = File::allFiles($mediaPath);
$allMedia = [];


foreach ($filesInFolder as $path) {
    $files = pathinfo($path);
    $allMedia[] = $files['basename'];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To list all files in directory use this

```
  $dir_path = public_path() . '/dirname';
   $dir = new DirectoryIterator($dir_path);
  foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: isFile could be useful here. It is more understandable for me

Answer (score 4):

*in laravel just use :*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

    $path = public_path();
    $files = File::allFiles($path);
  
    dd($files);
```

i hope it was useful !

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the files doing:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

..

```
$files = Storage::disk('local')->allFiles('public');
```

Answer (score 2):

To list all images in your public dir try this:
see here btw http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

```
  function getImageRelativePathsWfilenames(){

      $result = [];

    $dirs = File::directories(public_path());

    foreach($dirs as $dir){
      var_dump($dir); //actually string: /home/mylinuxiser/myproject/public"
      $files = File::files($dir);
      foreach($files as $f){
        var_dump($f); //actually object SplFileInfo
        //object(Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo)#628 (4) {
        //["relativePath":"Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo":private]=>
        //string(0) ""
        //["relativePathname":"Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo":private]=>
        //string(14) "text1_logo.png"
        //["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
        //string(82) "/home/mylinuxiser/myproject/public/img/text1_logo.png"
        //["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
        //string(14) "text1_logo.png"
        //}

        if(ends_with($f, ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif'])){
          $result[] = $f->getRelativePathname(); //prefix your public folder here if you want
        }
      }
    }
    return $result; //will be in this case ['img/text1_logo.png']
  }
```

Comment: how to convert it to laravel Image Object

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code and get all the subdirectories of a particular folder in the public folder. When some click the folder it lists the files inside each folder.

Controller File

```
 public function index() {

    try {

        $dirNames = array();  
        $this->folderPath = 'export'.DS.str_replace( '.', '_', $this->getCurrentShop->getCurrentShop()->shopify_domain ).DS.'exported_files';
        $getAllDirs = File::directories( public_path( $this->folderPath ) );

        foreach( $getAllDirs as $dir ) {

            $dirNames[] = basename($dir);

        }
        return view('backups/listfolders', compact('dirNames'));

    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        Log::error( $ex->getMessage() );
    }



}

public function getFiles( $directoryName ) {

    try {
        $filesArr = array();
        $this->folderPath = 'export'.DS.str_replace( '.', '_', $this->getCurrentShop->getCurrentShop()->shopify_domain ).DS.'exported_files'. DS . $directoryName;
        $folderPth = public_path( $this->folderPath );
        $files = File::allFiles( $folderPth ); 
        $replaceDocPath = str_replace( public_path(),'',$this->folderPath );

        foreach( $files as $file ) {

            $filesArr[] = array( 'fileName' => $file->getRelativePathname(), 'fileUrl' => url($replaceDocPath.DS.$file->getRelativePathname()) );

        }

        return view('backups/listfiles', compact('filesArr'));

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Log::error( $ex->getMessage() );
    }


}
```

Route ( Web.php )

```
Route::resource('displaybackups', 'Displaybackups\BackupController')->only([ 'index', 'show']);
```

Route::get('get-files/{directoryName}', 'Displaybackups\BackupController@getFiles');

View files - List Folders

```
@foreach( $dirNames as $dirName)
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 align-center">
        <a href="get-files/{{$dirName}}" class="btn btn-light folder-wrap" role="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open folderIcons"></span>
            {{ $dirName }}
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

View - List Files

```
@foreach( $filesArr as $fileArr)
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <a href="{{ $fileArr['fileUrl'] }}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn green folder-wrap">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file folderIcons"></span>
            <span class="file-name">{{ $fileArr['fileName'] }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel On-Demand Disks

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#on-demand-disks

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
 
$disk = Storage::build([
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/path/to/root',
]);
 
$disk->put('image.jpg', $content);
```

Additionaly, you can use `files` or `allFiles` methods to get files from another directories.

Both returns array, but `files` allow recursive way.

```
>>> man $disk->allFiles
class Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter implements Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Cloud, Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem
public function allFiles($directory = null)

Description:
  Get all of the files from the given directory (recursive).

Param:
  string|null  $directory 

Return:
  array 
>>> man $disk->files
class Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter implements Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Cloud, Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem
public function files($directory = null, $recursive = false)

Description:
  Get an array of all files in a directory.

Param:
  string|null  $directory 
  bool         $recursive 

Return:
  array 
>>>
```