# Get file list in a dynamic directory Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a folder structure in my `../storage/app/public` like this

`public
  --2017
    --January
       --Master.xls
       --File1.xls
       --File2.xls
    --February
    --March
    --...
    --December
  --2018
  --2019`

and I have a `html form` that allow the user to choose Year and Month using `dropdown input` button.
Now my question is, **how I can display a list of files in a directory (e.g. January) based on user's year and month selection?**

*I found this question is similar to [In Laravel 5, how can I obtain a list of all files in a public folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316543/in-laravel-5-how-can-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-public-folder) but it still doesn't clear enough for me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Storage::files($directory)` Will get you all files under a specific directory. Just construct the directory variable.

`$directory = 'app/public/'.$year.'/'.$month;`