# Zipping and downloading Amazon S3 bucket files and folders in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, zip

Is there a way to zip and download files and folders which are in Amazon S3 bucket, together in Laravel? I Want to zip the three folders and one file in the picture together and download it

[image]

Comment: You want it one time or as a functionality in laravel to zip s3 files?

Comment: as a functionality in laravel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a half baked solution in a route file.  Hope it helps.
https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/zip-archive/

```
    composer require league/flysystem-ziparchive
```

I put this in routes/web.php just to play with.

```
<?php   
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
    use League\Flysystem\ZipArchive\ZipArchiveAdapter;

    Route::get('zip', function(){

        // see laravel's config/filesystem.php for the source disk
        $source_disk = 's3';
        $source_path = '';

        $file_names = Storage::disk($source_disk)->files($source_path);

        $zip = new Filesystem(new ZipArchiveAdapter(public_path('archive.zip')));

        foreach($file_names as $file_name){
            $file_content = Storage::disk($source_disk)->get($file_name);
            $zip->put($file_name, $file_content);
        }

        $zip->getAdapter()->getArchive()->close();

        return redirect('archive.zip');

    });
```

You'll definitely want to do something different than just plopping it in the public dir.  Maybe stream it out straight out as a download or save it somewhere better.  Feel free to post comment/questions and we can discuss.

Comment: The files are zipping but not the folders inside the path... inside the three folders, there are additional folders with files...only files are zipped not the folders

Comment: @TauseefMamun In my solution I used files() ... there is a recursive version allfiles()

Comment: @TauseefMamun Take a look at my answer (not top answer) to this question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316543/in-laravel-5-how-can-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-public-folder/33931034#33931034

Comment: @TarekAdam is there a way to save the zip in S3 too?

Comment: @user1670816 change `public_path('archive.zip')` to app_path('archive.zip') Then use these 2 lines `Storage::disk('s3')->writeStream('archive2.zip', Storage::readStream('archive.zip'));
 Storage::disk('local')->delete('archive.zip');` and then redirect somewhere else because redirect('archive.zip') won't exist.  Basically this is creatinng a zip locally and pushing it off to s3.  Sorry I couldn't build the zip on s3, perhaps if you post a new question someone will do better.  FYI you need s3 configured in project/config/filesystems.php

Answer (score 7):

I did it the following way after looking at some solutions by streaming the zip directly to the client by using https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP :

```
if ($uploads) {

        return response()->streamDownload(function() use ($uploads) {

            $opt = new ArchiveOptions();

            $opt->setContentType('application/octet-stream');

            $zip = new ZipStream("uploads.zip", $opt);


            foreach ($uploads as $upload) {
                try {
                    $file = Storage::readStream($upload->path);
                    $zip->addFileFromStream($upload->filename, $file);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    \Log::error("unable to read the file at storage path: $upload->path and output to zip stream. Exception is " . $e->getMessage());
                }

            }

            $zip->finish();
        }, 'uploads.zip');
}
```

Comment: Best answer IMO, as the accepted answer is slower and requires you to handle the storage on your public dir.